# Why does Update operation on VarBinary Inserts new row instead of updating?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the varbinary(max) column with a new value which is also varbinary(max)
the end result is that I get a new row instead of updating the row.

**Sql**

```
CREATE proc Proc_UpdateFile      
@FileName varchar(50),  
@OldFileName varchar(50),       
@GuidNo varchar(50),      
@Img varbinary(max)      
as      
update tbl_BazImages set ImgName=@FileName , img = @Img where GuidNo=@GuidNo and ImgName=@OldFileName
```

**CodeBehid:**

```
 public bool UpdateFile(Byte[] bytes, string filename, string guidno,string OldFileName)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(claims_expense);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Proc_UpdateFile";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuidNo", guidno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", bytes);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldFileName", OldFileName);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eLog.WriteErrorLog(ex, "dboperation.cs", "UpdateFile");
            return false;
        }
        finally { con.Close(); }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't. What do you see that makes you think it is?

Comment: Perhaps there's an update trigger on that table that inserts a new row.

Comment: There is no trigger. 
But still update , inserts new row.

Comment: @Arbaaz Definitely not in the procedure you provided. So, look elsewhere.

Comment: @DenisValeev I have included my codebehind.

Comment: @DenisValeev and I have checked the value of OldFileName and it is correct i.e old file value

Comment: @Arbaaz You change the filename, maybe that's why you think you have a new row there. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, the code you have presented cannot insert records. There is something else happening in your system that you are missing.

I recommend using [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) with as much isoloation as you can manage to see what is actually happening.